# Suggestions to align vertically derivates and partial derivates

Tags: math-mode, macros, vertical-alignment, amsmath, brackets

For my book I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
Sapendo che $\xi=\xi(x,t)\in Y_{00}$, 
\[\left[\xi\frac{\partial f^{0}}{\partial \eta_t}\right]_{t_1}^{t_2}=0\]
per cui ripetendo lo stesso ragionamento per il terzo addendo, la si scriverà:
\[0=G'(0)=\iint_{D}\left[\frac{\partial f^{0}}{\partial\eta}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f^{0}}{\partial\eta_{x}}-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial f^{0}}{\partial\eta_{t}}\right]\xi dxdt\]
che per il lemma  darà luogo all'equazione
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f^{0}}{\partial\eta_{x}}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial f^{0}}{\partial\eta_{t}}\right)=\frac{\partial f^{0}}{\partial\eta}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to see that there is not a suboptimal alignment of the partial derivative symbol of the numerator and denominator due to the presence of the exponent `^{0}` (to see the red vertical segments).

There is also too much space between the partial derivative symbol and `f^{0}` (to see the red/orange boxes and the vertical green arrows).

[image]

> Is there a suggestion, a solution to align well vertically the partial derivatives with or without `^{0}`, reducing also the space, not altering the space between the formula inside the square or round brackets, without to align them using other packages?

Comment: Regarding the issue of there being too much space between `\partial` and `f` if the `newtxmath` math font package is in use: Please check if replacing all instances of `\partial f` with `\pf` and defining (in the preamble) `\newcommand\pf{\partial\mkern-2mu f}` helps.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much for your precious comment. +1

Comment: Add `\hfil` to terms that need to be pushed left.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hi....peraphs is it `\hfill`? I like very much upvoted ....hence I will wait your answers.

Comment: @Sebastiano -- `\hfil` is enough in this small expression, although it shouldn't make any difference.  You would need `\hfill` if you want to shove a whole line to the left, and there are other spaces in the line that might stretch.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for your comment. I not know of the command `\hfil`. Excuse to Steven for my previous comment.

Comment: @downvoter: Thank you very much (always) for your downvotes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unsightly denominators can be shifted fully leftward, by adding an `\hfill` to the end of the denominator term.  Originally, I had suggested `\hfil`, which shoves things partially to the left.

As to the poor kerning between `\partial` and `f`, I searched and replaced each `\partial f` into a new macro `\partialf`, which I defined as `\partial\mkern-2mu f`, which was Mico's suggestion.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\newcommand\partialf{\partial\mkern-2mu f}
\begin{document}
Sapendo che $\xi=\xi(x,t)\in Y_{00}$, 
\[\left[\xi\frac{\partialf^{0}}{\partial \eta_t\hfill}\right]_{t_1}^{t_2}=0\]
per cui ripetendo lo stesso ragionamento per il terzo addendo, la si scriverà:
\[0=G'(0)=\iint_{D}\left[\frac{\partialf^{0}}{\partial\eta\hfill}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partialf^{0}}{\partial\eta_{x}}-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partialf^{0}}{\partial\eta_{t}}\right]\xi dxdt\]
che per il lemma  darà luogo all'equazione
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partialf^{0}}{\partial\eta_{x}\hfill}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partialf^{0}}{\partial\eta_{t}\hfill}\right)=\frac{\partialf^{0}}{\partial\eta\hfill}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer +1 and the green check mark.